# Custom Scrollbar and Isotope

Tags: jquery, scrollbar, jquery-isotope

i try to implement [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/index.html) inside this [Custom Scrollbar](http://manos.malihu.gr/tuts/custom-scrollbar-plugin/complete_examples.html):

I wanna use the horizontal one and my code looks as follows:

```
// My Scrollbar
$(".content-selector").mCustomScrollbar({
      horizontalScroll:true,
      autoDraggerLength: true,                 
});

// My Isotope
var $container = $('.iso-container');
   $container.isotope({
       filter: '*',
       layoutMode: 'straightAcross',           
       resizesContainer: true,
       animationOptions: {
           duration: 750,
           easing: 'linear',
           queue: false
       }
   });

   $('.filter a').click(function(){

       $('.filter .current').removeClass('current');
       $(this).addClass('current');

       var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
       $container.isotope({
           filter: selector,
           animationOptions: {
               duration: 750,
               easing: 'linear',
               queue: false
           }
        }); 

        $(".content-selector").mCustomScrollbar("update");
        return false;

   });
```

My thoughts were, if i click one of the filter tags, the scrollbar should "update" like they explain in the documentation (width of the whole scrollbar). The problem is, it looks like he is trying it, but nothing happens so far. Do i forgot something or is my code just wrong?

Comment: anyone suggestions or ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably that the update method runs before isotope animations are completed. I think you should better use plugin's `updateOnContentResize` option parameter:

```
$(".content-selector").mCustomScrollbar({
    advanced:{
        updateOnContentResize: true
    }
});
```

or call the update method in isotope's `onLayout` callback option:

```
$container.isotope({
    filter: selector,
    animationOptions: {
        duration: 750,
        easing: 'linear',
        queue: false
    },
    onLayout: function( $elems, instance ) {
        $(".content-selector").mCustomScrollbar("update");
    }
});
```